Docker Checkpoint / Restore hanging
I installed criu and activated experimental setting in docker and trying to checkpoint and restore a fresh container :
docker run --name cn --network=host --mount type=bind, source=/mnt, target=/mnt -td sample_image:latest

The checkpoint is taken this way (and it causes the container to stop) :
pilot@thinkpad:~$ docker checkpoint create cn checkpt1
checkpt1

Then I used this command to restore it :
 pilot@thinkpad:~$ docker start --checkpoint checkpt1 cn

It hangs at the last command, and does not restart the container, I waited for many minutes and nothing happens. It keeps hanging there. and docker ps does not show anything running.
Am I missing something or doing anything wrong ? the docker image is debian 12 and everything is freshly installed and up to date. Any help is welcome.
